# ASP.NET MVC map one entity primary key relation to two columns on another entity as a Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I am having following two Models

**Ledger.cs**

```
public class Ledger
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Ledger name can not be empty")]
    public string NAME { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("MasterGroup")]
    [Display(Name = "Group")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Group can not be empty")]
    public int GROUPID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Category")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Category can not be empty")]
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Short Code")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Short code can not be empty")]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SHORTCODE { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    public virtual MasterGroup MasterGroup { get; set; }

    public List<Voucher> DrLedger { get; set; }
    public List<Voucher> CrLedger { get; set; }
}
```

**Voucher.cs**

```
public class Voucher
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [Required]
    public DateTime DATE { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Party")]

    public int DRPARTYID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Party")]

    public int CRPARTYID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Amount")]
    public decimal AMOUNT { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Narration")]
    public string NARRATION { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    [ForeignKey("MasterUser")]
    public string USERPASSWORD { get; set; }

    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public DateTime LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    public virtual MasterUser MasterUser { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("DRPARTYID")]
    public virtual Ledger DrLedger { get; set; }


    [ForeignKey("CRPARTYID")]
    public virtual Ledger CrLedger { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to create FK relation between these two entities.

`Ledger's` `ID` column as PK will be pointing twice to `Voucher's` `DRPARTYID` and `CRPARTYID` as two Foreign Key Relations.

I am getting following migration code, from which I don't want `Ledger_ID` to generated as FK.

**Migration Code**

```
public partial class AddedVoucherModelAndFKRelationsWithOtherModels : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Voucher",
            c => new
                {
                    ID = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    DATE = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    DRPARTYID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    CRPARTYID = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    AMOUNT = c.Decimal(nullable: false, precision: 18, scale: 2),
                    NARRATION = c.String(),
                    USERPASSWORD = c.String(maxLength: 50),
                    CREATE_TIMESTAMP = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP = c.DateTime(nullable: false),
                    Ledger_ID = c.Int(),//THIS SHOULD NOT BE GENERATED
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.ID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Ledger", t => t.CRPARTYID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Ledger", t => t.DRPARTYID, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.MasterUser", t => t.USERPASSWORD)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Ledger", t => t.Ledger_ID)
            .Index(t => t.DRPARTYID)
            .Index(t => t.CRPARTYID)
            .Index(t => t.USERPASSWORD)
            .Index(t => t.Ledger_ID);

    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Voucher", "Ledger_ID", "dbo.Ledger");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Voucher", "USERPASSWORD", "dbo.MasterUser");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Voucher", "DRPARTYID", "dbo.Ledger");
        DropForeignKey("dbo.Voucher", "CRPARTYID", "dbo.Ledger");
        DropIndex("dbo.Voucher", new[] { "Ledger_ID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Voucher", new[] { "USERPASSWORD" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Voucher", new[] { "CRPARTYID" });
        DropIndex("dbo.Voucher", new[] { "DRPARTYID" });
        DropTable("dbo.Voucher");
    }
}
```

How can I connect single column from one entity to two columns of another entity as a PK FK relations on specified columns?